# Stability and asymptotic stability of the equilibrium point $\tilde{y}$=0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes

Consider the ODE:$$ y'= sin(y)$$I have to investigate the stability and asymptotic stability of the equilibrium point $\tilde{y}$=0. Now we have defined an equilibrium point stable, in the sense of Ljapunov, if :$$\forall\epsilon\ \exists\delta>0\ : \| y(t_0)-\tilde{y}\|<\delta \rightarrow \|y(t)-\tilde{y}\|<\epsilon\ ,\forall t>t_0$$ and asymptotically stable, if there exists a neighbourhood $U_\tilde{y}$ of $\tilde{y}$ s.th. from $y(t_0)\in U_\tilde{y} $ it follows $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}y(t)=\tilde{y}$.

The problem I have right now is that solving the equation brings me to $$ \csc y - \cot y=e^{x+c_1}$$ and that I do not know how to go on from there.

It was said to be supposedly easy to check stability and asmyptotic stability but I do not see how I can find such $\delta$ for every $\epsilon$ 'easily'. Any help on how to check whether $\tilde{y}=0$ is stable or not would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So I found an easy criteria for asymptotically stable which we have written down , stating: if in $U_{\tilde{y}}$ it holds $f(y)<0$ for $y<\tilde{y}$ and $f(y)>0$ for $y>\tilde{y}$.

Comment: Not quite; you get stability when $f(y) > 0$ for $y < \bar y$ and $f(y) < 0$ for $y > \bar y$.  You wrote the criterion for *instability*, since $f(y) > 0$ means that $y$ will *increase* with $t$, and thus move *away* from $0$ rather than *towards* $0$ *und so weiter*.

Comment: We have called it a 'sink' if it is asymptotically stable making no sense the way I wrote it. I have written it down wrong then. But you are talking about stability and here I am talking about asymptotically stable, what is correct right now? @RobertLewis

Comment: So, with the definition of unstable and asymptotically stable one figures out that the equilibrium point here is unstable (However $\pi,3\pi...$ are all asymptotically stable points.)

Comment: Yes, that is right; $0$ is *unstable* but $(2m + 1) \pi$ is stable for all $m \in \Bbb Z$, whilst $2m\pi$ is *unstable* for all $m$.